# how to update configurable meta title to simple product's meta title in configurable products

Tags: php, magento

Written external script file to load simple products sku that are related to configurable product

Please find the script below for updating simple product meta title

```
/* Configurable product collection in $_product */

$conf = Mage::getModel('catalog/product_type_configurable')->setProduct($_product);
$simple_collection = $conf->getUsedProductCollection()->addAttributeToSelect(array('sku', 'name', 'meta_title'))->addFilterByRequiredOptions();

/* Making array of simple products from configurable product maping */
foreach($simple_collection as $simple_product) {
    $simpleProductList[$simple_product->getId()] = $simple_product->getSku();
}

/* updating each simple product meta title */
foreach($simpleProductList as $key => $skuValue) {
    $updPrd = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($key);
    $updPrd->setMetaTitle("[configurableProductMetaTitle]");
    $updPrd->save();
}
```

Each configurable product having nearly 400 to 500 simple products mapped.

While executing the script, its take too long time to update.

Please suggest how to optimize the code to execute the script in minimum period

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using something like this:

```
$conf = Mage::getModel('catalog/product_type_configurable')->setProduct($_product);
$simpleCollection = $conf->getUsedProductCollection()->addAttributeToSelect(array('sku', 'name', 'meta_title'))->addFilterByRequiredOptions();

$simpleIds = $simpleCollection->getAllIds();
$metaTitle = $conf->getProduct()->getMetaTitle();
$storeId = Mage::app()->getStore()->getStoreId(); // or define whatever store id you want

Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_action')->updateAttributes($simpleIds, array('meta_title' => $metaTitle), $storeId);
```

Key method is located under *app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Product/Action.php*

```
public function updateAttributes($productIds, $attrData, $storeId) {
    ...
}

$productIds // Array of your product ids you want to edit
$attrData // Array of data to be updated; array($attributeCode => $value)
$storeId // Id of store where you want changes to be applied
```

Hopefully this will give you lower execution time.

Cheers!